# Videos stop working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, firefox, suspend, google-chrome, video

Sometimes after waking my computer from sleep videos will no longer work. This applies to multiple websites including youtube and is not limited to a single browser.

I have tried refreshing the webpage, opening in a different browser, closing and reopening the browser, clearing cache and cookies etc. The only solution I have found is to restart the computer which is not a good solution.

I have searched for solutions online but can't find reports of anyone having the same or similar issue. All issues I find are either browser/webpage specific or are issues with videos stopping for a while and then resuming.

Answer (score 1):

It seems my pulseaudio server hangs and running these two commands fixes the issue:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
pulseaudio -k
```

I have not encountered the issue in a while now, it may just have been some bad config. I suspect the initial `killall` is redundant but since I have not encountered the issue I cannot test it. Hope this helps someone else!